# Magento 1.9.2.4 Order # wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I have just placed a test order and noticed that the Order # (44) is much lower than the last sale which occurred on my store Order # 85. How do I correct this?

Edit: Have added screenshot of eav_entity_store table.
[image]

Comment: What was the amount of order #85

Comment: $64.90 - my eav_entity_store table has many entries. Is this correct?

Comment: Okay, and what is the amount of order #44 ?

Comment: That was the order I just placed $339.90

Comment: Yes I got the issue. It is of unconverted quotes. Refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reference order Id or increment Id is generated in magento sequentially.
2. But if your new order is lower than the last placed order, that means it is the order generated by previous un-converted quote.
3. Uncoverted quote simply means that, when you add to product in cart and do not place order and logout, then after login that product automatically gets added in cart.
4. And even if you have placed different orders after that, the quote id of that cart remains lower because it was previously created.
5. So when you place order then only the quote gets converted, and remain lower in the table because it was previously created and you have placed some orders after that.

Comment: I do use a delete order extension. What will be the number of the next order?

Comment: Yes even if you delete the order, the magento will automatically generate the next order id wich is greater than one from previous order id. But if that order is of uncvoerted quote i.e old order which could not placed, then order id of that particular order will be same as old.

Comment: Order 45 already exists. Will it overwrite this order or go to Order #86 next?

Comment: If you place a new order right now its number will be #86

Comment: And if you create a quote right now and do not place the order and logout. And if other customers will give orders after that till number #103 or other. And if you again login your order will be #86 because it is of uncoverted quote.

Comment: Also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419592/how-to-change-order-starting-number-in-magento